# groupby and count aren't work correctly pandas

Tags: pandas, database, numpy, plot

I would like to take only product equal to `"Bikes"` from the table below and group the years. I need it to create a plot where i want show how the sale of bicycles has been over the years.

```
yearsbuy = df[['Year', 'Product_Category', 'Country']]
plot1 = yearsbuy.groupby('Year')['Product_Category'].value_counts()
plot1 = plot1['Product_Category'] =='Bikes'
```

When i did i get :

```
Year  Product_Category
2011  Bikes                2677
2012  Bikes                2677
2013  Accessories         15025
      Bikes                5710
      Clothing             3708
2014  Accessories         20035
```

But I want just only Bikes. Why `yearsbuy['Product_Category'] == "Bikes"` isn't working ?

Comment: Use this: `plot1 = plot1[plot1['Product_Category'] =='Bikes']`.

Comment: When I tired i get everytime error : KeyError: 'Product_Category'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we do a `value_counts()`, it gives the count as a pandas.Series for selected column, making the `Year` and `Product_Category` as indices (Mutli-index).

To obtain the columns `Year` and `Product_Category` back, we've to reset the index but the generated series raises a conflict since by default the Series takes the name of the column we're working with (`Product_Category`).
So I'm renaming that column containing count as `count` and resetting index to obtain the `Year` and `Product_Category` columns

```
plot1 = yearsbuy.groupby('Year')['Product_Category'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
plot1 = plot1[plot1['Product_Category'] =='Bikes']
```

Comment: I get error : TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame

Comment: C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)
index Year Product_Category

Comment: The updated one should work.

Comment: Amazing thanks ! Could you explaine me step by step what's happend after value.count()

Comment: Updated my solution.

Comment: May I ask one more thing : If i want add "Country" : df[['Country','Year','Product_Category']]
plot2 = df.groupby('Year')[['Country','Product_Category']].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()

Comment: add "Country" as in? The previous one can give you sales of Bicycles over the years. What do you intend to visualize in this case?

Comment: I'd like to show you how much each country has sold over the years. Because in this graph, I showed the total sum

Comment: In that case, you can simply replace `Product_Category` with `country`

Comment: Yeah i did. Thank you a lot. Have a nice evening ! take care